# CAMLQuery with multiple and/or

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml

I want to be able to check if
(1 = 1) AND (2=2 OR 3=3)

this is the following code i've tried so far:

```
"<View>" +
"<Query>" +
"<Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + namn + "</Value></Eq>" +
"<Or>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>Hög</Value></Eq>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Startad</Value></Eq>" +
"</Or>" +
"</And>" +
"</Where>" +
"</Query>" +
"</View>");
```

Comment: Please put parenthesis in what you want to check. It's not possible to provide answer as it differs whether you want to do "(1 = 1 and 2=2) or 3=3" or "1 = 1 and (2=2 or 3=3)". Currently your query does "1 = 1 and (2=2 or 3=3)".

Comment: @JussiPalo edited!

Comment: It looks good to me, you getting some error that query is malformed, or not the desired result?

Comment: @JussiPalo Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 403(forbidden)

Comment: Issue is not with CAML, please post the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the view and query tags from the CAML, are you facing any error?

```
 "<Where>" +
"<And>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + namn + "</Value></Eq>" +
"<Or>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>Hög</Value></Eq>" +
"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Startad</Value></Eq>" +
"</Or>" +
"</And>" +
"</Where>"
```